# Is it possible to work with directories in Rust?

Tags: rust

Can I use a module that is located inside the directory that is located next to the executable file?

```
--src
   |
   |--main.rs
   |
   |--dir
   |   |--my_file.rs
```

I don't really want to start a new crate, but I can't write something like:

```
mod my_file;
```

or

```
mod dir::my_file;
```

Comment: Why can't you put `mod my_file;` and have `my_file.rs`?

Comment: It seems to me that I will have more files for my_file.rs and I would like to put the logic in a separate directory. This is just an example.

Comment: `my_file/mod.rs`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, In addition, it is not clear to me if I create a crate, I should always take out all open methods in lib.rs ?

Comment: Maybe [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html) of the Rust book would be of assistance to you?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, suppose that in the file my_file.rs the `my_file` module is stored

Comment: @IanS. I read this section, but I still did not understand whether it is possible to work with directories and what is the advantage of crates in general

Comment: @student213 are you aware that the executable is also a crate? A crate is just the unit of rust compilation. The executable is just a special type of crate that has the root called `main.rs` by convention rather than `lib.rs`. Otherwise everything is exactly the same as if the file was called `lib.rs`. Don't create a seperate crate or anything, just put the module declartions in your `main.rs`.

Answer (score 2):

If you know Python, Rust's modules are somewhat similar to Python's packages in that the directories are not intrinsically meaningful, a "signal" file is necessary to make them so.

For historical reaons, in rust there are two options for that signal files:

- a `mod.rs` file nested inside the directory
- or a `dir.rs` file next to the directory

Both work and their behaviour is equivalent, so it mostly comes down to how you come at it. `mod.rs` has the advantage that it makes the entire module into a unit you can move around, while `dir.rs` provides a clearer descriptor and makes it easier to start with a single file then split things out later on.

So in the above what you need is to add a `dir.rs` or `dir/mod.rs` which contains:

```rust
mod my_file;
```

and `main.rs` should contain the stanza

```rust
mod dir;
```

and things should work out, `dir` and `dir::my_file` now become available (in sibling modules you may need to `use` them).

> In addition, it is not clear to me if I create a crate, I should always take out all open methods in lib.rs ?

I don't understand what you're talking about, what is an "open method"?

> [...] what is the advantage of crates in general

In Rust a crate is a unit of:

- visibility, a crate is a single thing which impacts visibility (`pub(crate)` and a few other things) and orphan rules (you can only implement a trait on a type if either was defined in the current crate), a crate can also have circular dependencies internally (not that it's necessarily a good thing though it's often convenient) while intra-crate dependencies must be a DAG
- code distribution, a crate is a unit you can upload to cargo (or an equivalent private repository) and depend on
- code generation, different crates can always be built concurrently (as long as they don't depend on one another, obviously), intra-crate concurrency is a lot less reliable